# Cual es el significado de static get en Javascript?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-2015

Una expresion en Javascript me ha dejado un tanto confuso:

```
static get is() { return "custom-element"; }
```

Cual es el funcionamiento de un static get en Javascript? Supongo que el static tiene una funcion similar a lo que se hace en Java o C++.

Answer (score 3):

Es la forma de definir `getters` y `setters` en EcmaScript 6, también llamados accesores. Los accesores sirven para acceder a propiedades privadas de una instancia como si se accediese directamente a la propiedad, pero en realidad el acceso se hace través de una función. Esto permite mantener un control sobre lo que se lee y lo que se escribe en la propiedad, manteniendo la propiedad privada. De esta forma, se pueden hacer todo tipo de validaciones o transformaciones al dato de entrada para mantener la coherencia lógica de la instancia. En Internet seguramente puedas encontrar explicaciones más detalladas y completas de su uso que está improvisada explicación.

Respecto a la sintáxis, la cosa tiene miga. Aunque JavaScript hereda bastantes cosas de Java y C++ hay que tener cuidado porque también tiene cosas muy diferentes, principalmente su dinamismo. JavaScript es un lenguaje cuya orientación a objetos está basada en la herencia de prototipos en vez de herencia clásica como C++ o Java.

El código que muestras usa la nueva forma añadida a JavaScript para facilitar el uso del lenguaje de una forma más parecida a la herencia clásica. De hecho, si lo comparamos con la herencia clásica hay algo raro. El código define un método, `is()`, de forma estática. Esto, en POO de herencia clásica implicaría que el método solo tiene acceso a las propiedades y métodos estáticos de la clase, pero no se podría ejecutar sobre una instancia. Sin embargo, como he indicado antes, JavaScript tiene una herencia basada en prototipos. Baste decir que que los objetos tienen un prototipo padre del que heredan sus métodos (en JavaScript no hay realmente clases, aunque se haya añadido `class`).

El código que comentas lo que hace es añadir el getter id() al constructor de la instancia, que es en JavaScript el *prototipo* de la instancia. De esta forma, el getter es solo definido en un punto (en el objeto que construye la instancias) pero está disponible para todas las instancias.

**NOTA**: En JAvaScript si se intenta ejecutar un método que no existe en una instancia el motor de JavaScript busca ese mismo método en los *prototipos* de la instancia. Si lo encuentra lo ejecuta; si termina de buscar en todos los prototipos sin encontrarlo se lanzará un error.

Comment: +1 por escribir "acceder" en vez de "accesar" :)